# multiply all contents of two arrays in ruby to get a third array

Tags: ruby

This is what I am trying to get:

```
Array1=[a,b,c]

Array2=[d,e,f]

=> [a*d,a*e,a*f,b*d,b*e,b*f,c*d,c*e,c*f]
```

How can you do this in ruby? So far I can only return `[a*d,b*e,c*f]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-product) method.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [3, 5, 6]

array1.product(array2).map { |a, b| a * b }
# => [3, 5, 6, 6, 10, 12, 9, 15, 18]
```

Comment: OP means the actual product I suppose.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Its a problem sometime to guess. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Array1.product(Array2).map{|x, y| x * y}
```

Comment: this post showed up in the low quality queue. It was determined to be a low quality answer, this is an automated comment.

Comment: @sawa - it is the canned message for "this answer should be a comment" - because your answer is code only, it is automatically flagged as "low quality" - apparently staticx agreed with that...

Comment: @sawa - I don't agree with staticx that it is a low quality answer, no - staticx is not a robot, just an avid SO user, who has a review privilege, and got your question in the low quality review queue

Comment: @sawa The answer was still correct of mine. The only thing is OP didn't provide valid data. Both of we took a guess, you win and I lost. But the approach was correct. My guess was inputs are *string*.Thus the answer was based on *string*. Later, it got confirmed, the inputs are *integer*, so it got changed. Still OP's data is invalid. It is OP's *fault*, not ours. So Chill.. :-)